# What is a fake name in cinematography called?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-in-context

> Ronald Weasley is Rupert Grint's ___(name) in the Harry Potter.

These are some possibilities I could think of:

> 1. fake name
> 2. role name
> 3. acting name

Is there maybe a single word for this?

Comment: Maybe pseudonym?

Comment: Do you mean a name of a character? This is what you have in your example. Or, do you mean an assumed name that someone uses instead of their real name? Such as Marion Morrison taking the name John Wayne when he became an actor. That would be a stage name or a screen name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Role" is enough. Rupert's role was Ron Weaseley.

You could also say "He played the character of Ron" or "His part was Ron".  If you need to mention names: "The name of Rupert's character was Ron".